# What could cause the logging module to log a record multiple times?

Tags: python, logging

I have a multi-threaded Python application that makes use of the [built in logging](http://docs.python.org/library/logging.html) module.  To control the logging levels and make it easier to swap the `StreamHandler` with a `FileHandler` in the future, I have created a common helper function called by each module to create an identical logger (other than its name).

**How should I go about trouble shooting this issue?**

**Key Points**

1. Each module in the project has its own logger instance.
2. The sample output is generated by a single call to a logger (`self._logger.info("Logger Setup")`)
3. I have tried including the current thread name (`threading.Thread.getName()`) and it confirms that the same thread is calling causing the multiple logs.

**Logger Creation - Now working**

```
import logging
import sys
def createSystemLogHandler(logger):
    # This is now called once at the logger's root 
    ch = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout) # Normal output is to stderr which doesn't show up on Window's CMD
    format = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(name)s - %(message)s')
    ch.setFormatter(format)
    logger.addHandler(ch)
    return logger

def configureSystemLogger(name='', level=logging.WARNING):
        logger = logging.getLogger(name)
        logger.setLevel(level)
        logger.info("Logger Setup")
        return logger
```

**Sample Output**

```
2012-04-25 21:59:40,720 - INFO - HW_MGR - Logger Setup
2012-04-25 21:59:40,720 - INFO - HW_MGR - Logger Setup
2012-04-25 21:59:40,720 - INFO - HW_MGR - Logger Setup
2012-04-25 21:59:40,720 - INFO - HW_MGR - Logger Setup
2012-04-25 21:59:40,720 - INFO - HW_MGR - Logger Setup
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that you've got multiple handlers (ie, one message is being emitted multiple times; but on re-reading your question, it looks like you already knew that). To debug that, try:

- Looking at `logging.getLogger("").handlers` (ie, the handlers on the root logger)
- Checking your calls to `addHandler()`
- [Brandon Rhode's](http://twitter.com/#!/brandon_rhodes) [`logging_tree`](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/logging_tree) module
- Use [`pdb`](http://docs.python.org/library/pdb.html) to trace a log message's lifecycle (ie, put a breakpoint just before a call to `self._logger.info(…)`, then step into that function).

Comment: Well I "knew" that I had multiple handlers, but it didn't register for me that all of them would call its `emit` on each message.