# Logging module sample code repeats messages n-times-each call

Tags: python, logging, ipython

I'm surprised by the output from Python's logging module. I wrote up the Python.org's [How-To for Logging](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html#configuring-logging). When I run the sample code, there is a lot of (confusing) duplication.

The StreamHandler duplicates the log messages, one for each time I reload the file in iPython with the magic `%run`

```
In [4]: %run main.py
2018-05-11 2127:33 - WARNING - 3. This is a warning, yous!
2018-05-11 2127:33 - ERROR - 4. Here is an error
2018-05-11 2127:33 - CRITICAL - 5. This is f-ing critical!
[...]
In [7]: %run main.py
2018-05-11 2127:38 - WARNING - 3. This is a warning, yous!
2018-05-11 2127:38 - WARNING - 3. This is a warning, yous!
2018-05-11 2127:38 - WARNING - 3. This is a warning, yous!
2018-05-11 2127:38 - ERROR - 4. Here is an error
2018-05-11 2127:38 - ERROR - 4. Here is an error
2018-05-11 2127:38 - ERROR - 4. Here is an error
2018-05-11 2127:38 - CRITICAL - 5. This is f-ing critical!
2018-05-11 2127:38 - CRITICAL - 5. This is f-ing critical!
2018-05-11 2127:38 - CRITICAL - 5. This is f-ing critical!
```

I added a FileHandler:

```
fh = logging.FileHandler("app.log")
fh.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
fh.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(fh)
```

This also duplicates:

```
xtian@spaceghost> cat app.log
2018-05-11 2159:24 - WARNING - 3. This is a warning!
2018-05-11 2159:24 - ERROR - 4. This is an error
2018-05-11 2159:24 - CRITICAL - 5. This is fucking critical!
[...]
2018-05-11 2201:00 - WARNING - 3. This is a warning, yous!
2018-05-11 2201:00 - WARNING - 3. This is a warning, yous!
2018-05-11 2201:00 - WARNING - 3. This is a warning, yous!
2018-05-11 2201:00 - ERROR - 4. Here is an error.
2018-05-11 2201:00 - ERROR - 4. Here is an error.
2018-05-11 2201:00 - ERROR - 4. Here is an error.
2018-05-11 2201:00 - CRITICAL - 5. This is f-ing critical!
2018-05-11 2201:00 - CRITICAL - 5. This is f-ing critical!
2018-05-11 2201:00 - CRITICAL - 5. This is f-ing critical!
```

I also followed the suggestions from [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47440034/python-2-logger-repeats-lines-after-use-of-default-logger) [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30628487/python-logs-displaying-multiple-times-in-stdout), and added these lines just before the message calls:

```
# propagation fix
logger.propagate = False
```

The results are the same.

---

Setting up to post, I see a similar question:

[What could cause the logging module to log a record multiple times?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10326768/what-could-cause-the-logging-module-to-log-a-record-multiple-times)

But all this debugging is for the OP's original custom code. My issue is with the sample code, which I expect should warn or explain better what's happening.

The docs say,

> Note. If you attach a handler to a logger and one or more of its ancestors,
>   it may emit the same record multiple times. In general, you should not
>   need to attach a handler to more than one logger - if you just attach
>   it to the appropriate logger which is highest in the logger hierarchy,
>   then it will see all events logged by all descendant loggers, provided
>   that their propagate setting is left set to True. A common scenario is
>   to attach handlers only to the root logger, and to let propagation
>   take care of the rest.

You can see the full test file `main.py` [here](https://ptpb.pw/Sk_j) to see if I have *'more than one logger'*.

```
import logging

# Root Logger
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

# Console handler
ch = logging.StreamHandler()
ch.setLevel(logging.WARNING)

# Formatter
formatter = logging.Formatter(fmt='%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s' , datefmt='%Y-%m-%d %H%M:%S', style='%')

# Add formatter to Console handler ch
ch.setFormatter(formatter)

# Add ch to logger
logger.addHandler(ch)

# Text File handler
fh = logging.FileHandler("app.log")
fh.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
fh.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(fh)

# propagation fix
logger.propagate = False

# Example Application code
logger.debug("1. This is a debug message.")
logger.info("2. This is an info message.")
logger.warning('3. This is a warning!')
logger.error('4. This is an error')
logger.critical("5. This is fucking critical!")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `logger` returned by `logging.getLogger(__name__)` is the same logger each time `%run main.py` is executed. But

```
ch = logging.StreamHandler()
```

instantiates a new StreamHandler each time, which is then added to the `logger`:

```
logger.addHandler(ch)
```

Thus, on subsequent runs of `%run main.py`, the `logger` has multiple handlers
attached to it and a record gets emitted by each handler.

---

```
In [5]: %run main.py
2018-05-11 2251:17 - WARNING - 3. This is a warning!
2018-05-11 2251:17 - ERROR - 4. This is an error
2018-05-11 2251:17 - CRITICAL - 5. This is fucking critical!

In [6]: logger
Out[6]: <logging.Logger at 0x7f5d0152fe10>
```

The first time `%run main.py` is run, two handlers are attached to `logger`:

```
In [7]: logger.handlers
Out[12]: 
[<logging.StreamHandler at 0x7f5d0152fdd8>,
 <logging.FileHandler at 0x7f5d014c40f0>]

In [13]: %run main.py
2018-05-11 2251:44 - WARNING - 3. This is a warning!
2018-05-11 2251:44 - WARNING - 3. This is a warning!
2018-05-11 2251:44 - ERROR - 4. This is an error
2018-05-11 2251:44 - ERROR - 4. This is an error
2018-05-11 2251:44 - CRITICAL - 5. This is fucking critical!
2018-05-11 2251:44 - CRITICAL - 5. This is fucking critical!
```

The second time, there are now four handlers:

```
In [14]: logger.handlers
Out[14]: 
[<logging.StreamHandler at 0x7f5d0152fdd8>,
 <logging.FileHandler at 0x7f5d014c40f0>,
 <logging.StreamHandler at 0x7f5d014c4668>,
 <logging.FileHandler at 0x7f5d014c4550>]

In [15]: logger
Out[15]: <logging.Logger at 0x7f5d0152fe10>
```

To prevent duplication, you could call `logger.removeHandler` between `%run` calls:

```
In [29]: for handler in logger.handlers: logger.removeHandler(handler)

In [30]: %run main.py
2018-05-11 2257:30 - WARNING - 3. This is a warning!
2018-05-11 2257:30 - ERROR - 4. This is an error
2018-05-11 2257:30 - CRITICAL - 5. This is fucking critical!
```

or, modify `main.py` so that new handlers are not attached each time `%run` is called.
For example, you could setup `logger` using [`logging.config.dictConfig`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/logging.config.html#logging.config.dictConfig):

```
import logging
import logging.config

# Modified using https://stackoverflow.com/a/7507842/190597 as a template
logging_config = { 
    'version': 1,
    'formatters': { 
        'standard': { 
            'format': '%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s'
        },
    },
    'handlers': { 
        'stream': { 
            'level': 'INFO',
            'formatter': 'standard',
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
        },
        'file': { 
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'formatter': 'standard',
            'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
            'filename': 'app.log'
        },
    },
    'loggers': { 
        __name__: { 
            'handlers': ['stream', 'file'],
            'level': 'WARN',
            'propagate': False
        },
    } 
}
logging.config.dictConfig(logging_config)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

# Example Application code
logger.debug("1. This is a debug message.")
logger.info("2. This is an info message.")
logger.warning('3. This is a warning!')
logger.error('4. This is an error')
logger.critical("5. This is fucking critical!")
```

Using this code, `%run main.py` emits the same output each time.

Comment: How do you prevent duplication?

Comment: You could remove the handlers between `%run` calls. I've edited the post above to show what I mean.

Comment: Alternatively, use [`logging.config`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/logging.config.html) to setup `logger` without adding new handlers each time `%run main.py` is called.

Comment: _modify main.py so that new handlers are not attached each time_ Curious that the `dictConfig` version doesn't attach handlers each time.

Comment: With `dictConfig` you get to specify the *state* of the loggers. Under the hood, `dictConfig` [calls `removeHandler`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/logging/config.py#L766). With `'handlers': ['stream', 'file']` you just get the two handlers.

Comment: Note. I'm adding loggers from other modules loaded into `main.py`. Each has the line `import logging; logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)`. Seems the setting `'loggers' : { __name__ : {...}}` didn't work to bring in the other loggers. I needed,     `'loggers': { '' : {...}}`.